# Ajax on php with CI, gets undefined index term

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in PHP, I followed a tutorial and in live search engine I got no result when typing charactors.I am suspicious to view index where I address source, but I am not sure. Sorry if the code is long!

Controller product.php

```
    <?php
class Product extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('index');
          $this->load->model('mproduct');
         $result = $this->mproduct->search($_GET['term']);
          echo "this is search";
        if(count($result)>0) {
            foreach ($result as $pr)
                $arr_result[] = $pr->name;
        }
        echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
}
```

Model mproduct.php

```
<?php
class MProduct extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function search($name) {
        $this->db->like('name',$name, 'both');
        return $this->db->get('product')->result();

    }
}

?>
```

view index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <link href="/phpAmir_contract/assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/css" src="/phpAmir_contract/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css"></script>
        <script type="text/css" src="/phpAmir_contract/assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"></script>
        <script   type="text/javascript"   src="/phpAmir_contract/assets/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
          <script   type="text/javascript"   src="/phpAmir_contract/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">


        <title> demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()){
            $('#production').autocomplete({

                source: "/phpAmir_contract/application/controllers/product/search"

            })
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" name ="productname" id="productname"/> 

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the error I get now]

Comment: Is your product name being sent on a GET var or on the url ? If it's being sent through a GET var why do you need the '/?' at the end of your url ?

Comment: Can only echo once with json, move `echo` out of the loop...need to return something if there are no results also

Comment: Why is your source url like that? You do not need to give the url like that. Taking `phpAmir_contract` as your root folder your url should be this: `phpAmir_contract/index.php/product/search`.

Comment: @charlietfl how can i return as jason and get it in view?

Comment: did you move the echo out of the loop? and fix url as pointed out also

Comment: @charlietfl I changed the url as it says and put echo after loop. but still same!

Comment: have you dumped the db query data to see if it returns what you expect?

Comment: @charlietfl, I used   print_r($arr_result); in controller at the end, and it returns nothing, so it means no data from model?

Comment: yes that's what it means.

Comment: @charlietfl, do you see any problem in my model? I can not find it!

Comment: can use `echo $db->last_query()` to see actual sql statement and then test that in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @charlietfl I put echo $db->last_query() at the end of my model, and no respond. I dont know how to test in phpmyadmin.

Comment: can't help much, you will need to learn more about how to access db with phpMyAdmin or other db tools and learn how to debug php

Comment: @charlietfl I changed the controller as you can see and now I get an undefined term, how can I define term here?

Comment: Problem 1: There is no input with the ID `production` in your HTML.
Problem 2: Open console and go to the tab 'Network' and see the response